# R install package question

Tags: r

I'm trying to install `infochimp library` on my R.

```
(*from drewconway-infochimps-13d899c.zip - infochimp folder contains folders man, R and files DESCRIPTION, LICENSE, NAMESPACE)
```

I have installed:

```
-Developers toolkit
-RJSONIO
-RCURL
-twitteR
```

However, when I copy the library directly to the relevant directory (same technique as I used for RJSONIO) it doesn't show up in the install package menu.

On Windows platform

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you were using dashes rather than backslashes to designate directory location and that the actual file name is  "13d899c.zip" and the full path to that file is "\from drewconway\infochimps\" then in an open session of R try this:

```
install.packages(pkgs="\\from drewconway\\infochimps\\13d899c.zip" )
```

(Paths in R under Windows need to have either doubled backslashes or single forward slashes. Packages in zip format should be in binary format which is the default type. You should learn to be more careful about how you communicate the path construction and if the "\from drewconway\" guess is wrong, then correct it.)

Comment: Genius. Spent ages trying to bloody install a package.